# Using Ajax to have a sequential set of DB derived radio buttons

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have never worked with Ajax before and I am playing around a bit trying to learn it (i like to understand something before just going to jquery like a colleague suggested). I have a page which starts with a radio button (options taken from a DB), which onselect should trigger a new radiobutton (again, options taken from a DB). I started with simply showing the results from the initial 'select' but nothing happens when i select something from the radio button and i don't really understand why. I would love it if someone is able to tell me why this doesn't do what I expect it to do.

Thanks in advance

Main Page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function showGlycopeptides(str)
      {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (str=="")
        {
          document.getElementById("txtField").innerHTML="";
          return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else 
        {
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
            document.getElementById("txtField").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getglycopeptides.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    </script>
    <title>LeidenGlycoPeptide DataBase</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the LeidenGlycoPeptide DataBase</h1>
    <?php
      $link = mysql_connect("localhost","reader","") or die (mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db('leidenGlycoPeptide') or die ();
      $query = 'select protein from glycoPeptide';
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      mysql_close($link);  
    ?>
    <form>
      <p>Select glycopeptide to search for (interactive dialog)</p>
      <?php
         echo"<select name=\"prec\" onchange=\"showGlycopeptides(this.value)\">";
         echo"<option value=\"\">select glycoprotein</option>";
         while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
           foreach ($line as $col_value) {
             echo"<option value=\"$col_value\">$col_value</option>";
           }
         } 
         echo"</select>";
       ?>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtField"><b>Text field</b></div>
  </body>
```

getglycopeptides.php:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>glyco</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $q=$_GET["q"];
      $link = mysql_connect("localhost","reader","") or die (mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db("leidenGlycoPeptide",$link) or die();
      $query = "select glycoType from run,glycoPeptide where run.id = glycoPeptide.id and glycoPeptide.protein like '".$q."'";
      echo "<select name=\"type\" onchange=\"foo\">";
      echo "<option value=\"\">select glycosylation</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
      {
        foreach ($row as $col_value)
          {
            echo"<option value=\"$col_value\">$col_value</option>";
          }
      }
      echo "</select>";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      mysql_close($link);
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

---- EDITED ----

The code was edited so that they can serve as an example (for others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to post this as an answer, but I haven't unlocked the ability to post comments.

My guess is that the problem is in the ajax request, because the PHP file getglycopeptides.php is going to return something back even if the query parameter wasn't send.

An easy way to verify this is to use the network panel on chrome or the console panel in firefox firebug.

Check that a new request is being made when you select a different option from the select.

Another way would be to use console.log('Something'); where you get the ajax response, if you see the 'Something' being printed in the console then the ajax is being fired. Just remember that console.log doesn't work in IE.

Just verify this first so we can rule it out and we could spot the problem.

Comment: Oh, and another thing I just spoted. You need to define the xmlhttp variable and you haven't. Just add `var xmlhttp;` at the beggining of your showGlycopeptides function

Comment: I love the console part of firebug, going to give you a upvote and accept this answer. I managed to spot the (extremely silly) mistake that was causing this to fail.